# How to forward Docker for Mac to X11?

Tags: macos, docker, xquartz

Using [Docker for Mac 1.12 (stable)](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/#/download-docker-for-mac) and OS X 10.11.5 (15F34), I'm attempting to make one of my containers forward to X11.

First, I install XQuartz from my bash shell:

```
$ brew cask install xquartz

==> Downloading https://dl.bintray.com/xquartz/downloads/XQuartz-2.7.9.dmg
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Verifying checksum for Cask xquartz
==> Running installer for xquartz; your password may be necessary.
==> Package installers may write to any location; options such as --appdir are ignored.
Password:
==> installer: Package name is XQuartz 2.7.9
==> installer: Installing at base path /
==> installer: The install was successful.
  xquartz staged at '/usr/local/Caskroom/xquartz/2.7.9' (73M)
```

Then I continue with setting up XQuartz...

```
open -a XQuartz
```

In the XQuartz Preferences -> Security tab, I enable "Allow connections from network clients".

Then I am supposed to run `xhost + $MY_IP_ADDRESS` in my bash shell, but all I get is this error:

```
xhost:  unable to open display ""
```

In the end, all guides I'm reading says I should run my container like this:

```
docker run -e DISPLAY=$MY_IP_ADDRESS:0 -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix DOCKER_IMAGE
```

...but that doesn't work. In my particular container, I get this error:

```
... cannot connect to X server 10.0.0.131:0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out there's a bug in XQuartz 2.7.9.

When using XQuartz 2.7.10_beta2, it works.

Comment: I had the same problem with ver 2.7.11. 
I uninstalled and downgraded it to 2.7.10_beta2 and everything finally works. I just had to restart (instead of just log-out) and things started to work

Comment: I had a heckuva time with this... downgraded, etc. Turned out the issue was a mere reboot was necessary. Running flawlessly now on XQuartz 2.7.11 with Docker CE version 17.12.0 on MacOS 10.13.3.

Comment: Excellent Jobs. It works when I have downgraded XQuaterz to 2.7.10_beta2.

Answer (score 2):

I have xQuartz 2.7.11 installed on Mac OS.

I was getting the following error 

`<program>: cannot connect to X server <ip>:0`

when trying to run docker container. I tried downgrading XQuartz but it still didn't fix my issue.

A crucial piece to to the setup is to add your ip access control list for xhost.

`xhost + $(ipconfig getifaddr en0)`

After adding the ip to xhost, everything works. There is no need to downgrade Xquartz version.

Comment: 2.7.11 didn't work for me (macOS Sierra 10.12.4 + Docker CE 17.03.1). I had to downgrade to 2.7.10_beta2 to make it work.

Comment: where is xhost?

Comment: The xhost command should be entered in the xterm window of XQuartz

Answer (score 2):

## Solution

After installing XQuartz you will **need to restart your computer** as [horcle_buzz suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38686932/how-to-forward-docker-for-mac-to-x11#comment84886444_38687836); starting a new terminal session is not enough.

After a reboot you can grant access for whatever you need using the `xhost` command. Just be careful and understand the consequences of too permissive a rule. This other discussion has more info: [Running Chromium inside Docker - Gtk: cannot open display: :0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28392949/running-chromium-inside-docker-gtk-cannot-open-display-0/34586732#comment63471630_28395350)

## Additional findings

Some extra things I discovered along the way:

- XQuartz **must** be running first:

  ```sh
  $ open -a XQuartz
  ```
- You can expose `127.0.0.1` instead of looking up your local IP *(caveat emptor: I'm not an expert on the implications of this setting):*

  ```sh
  $ xhost + 127.0.0.1
  127.0.0.1 being added to access control list
  ```
- You can use the special `host.docker.internal` identifier with `docker run`:

  ```sh
  $ docker run -e DISPLAY=host.docker.internal:0 jess/firefox
  # ‍♀️ magic ‍♂️
  ```
- At least for me, `ctrl + c` does not shutdown the container; I need to close the X11 window manually.
- If you quit XQuartz, you **must** re-auth with `xhost` after starting it again (the permission doesn't "stick").
- Doing it this way I didn't need to mount `/tmp/.X11-unix` when calling `docker run`.

I tested this with XQuartz 2.7.11 and Docker Desktop 2.1.0.2 on macOS Mojave (10.14.6).