# Unable to init Xserver inside a docker container on PopOS

Tags: linux, docker, user-interface, docker-compose, xserver

I have a use-case where I need to run a GUI application from Docker and display it on either a Windows or a Linux host. (In this example I try it with firefox)

**For Windows, it works** as intended [using vcxsrv](https://dev.to/darksmile92/run-gui-app-in-linux-docker-container-on-windows-host-4kde). However, no matter what I try on Linux (`Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS` specifically), I always get the following error:

```
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Error: cannot open display: <my_display>
```

Here is a list of the things I've tried so far to no avail

- Adding the `/tmp` to the mount path in Docker Desktop - [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68495984/10543130)
- Allowing global access to XServer `xhost +` and [other variations](https://github.com/jessfraz/dockerfiles/issues/329)
- Setting `$DISPLAY` to various values (':0', '<my-ip>:1', '<my-ip>:0', etc...) - [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28395350/10543130)
- Setting `privileged: true` and `network_mode: host` in compose
- Installing `xauth` inside the container as shown in `init-script.sh` and `Dockerfile` below - [mentioned here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1234927/1202781)
- Creating and mounting the file `~/.Xauthority` since I don't have it on my system
- Adding a `--runtime=runc` to the run command - [mentioned here](https://community.clearlinux.org/t/execute-graphical-applications-from-docker/698/11)

Output of `uname -a`

```bash
Linux pop-os 5.19.0-76051900-generic #202207312230~1663791054~22.04~28340d4 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Wed S x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Content of `ls -l /tmp/.X11-unix`

```bash
srwxrwxrwx 1 sina sina 0 Oct 18 13:48 X1
```

My file tree is as follows:

```
├── docker-compose.yml
├── Dockerfile
└── init-script.sh
```

The files and their content:

`docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  firefox:
    build: .
    image: firefox:latest
    container_name: firefox-in-docker
    environment:
      - DISPLAY=${DISPLAY} # 'host.docker.internal:0.0' is what works for windows if you're curious
    volumes:
      - /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix
```

`Dockerfile`

```sh
FROM ubuntu:20.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y firefox
# RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y xauth

COPY init-script.sh /opt/program/init-script.sh
CMD ["/bin/bash", "/opt/program/init-script.sh"]
```

`init-script.sh`

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# HOST=root
# DISPLAY_NUMBER=$(echo $DISPLAY | cut -d. -f1 | cut -d: -f2)
# AUTH_COOKIE=$(xauth list | grep "^$(hostname)/unix:${DISPLAY_NUMBER} " | awk '{print $3}')
# xauth add ${HOST}/unix:${DISPLAY_NUMBER} MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 ${AUTH_COOKIE}

/usr/bin/firefox
```

Of course, I also don't forget to re-build and run the image every time I make a change to the `Dockerfile` with `docker compose build && docker compose up`.

There is one thing I didn't try, which is running a VNC Server [(scroll down close to the end)](https://www.howtogeek.com/devops/how-to-run-gui-applications-in-a-docker-container/) but I really wanted to know what's wrong with XServer.

Comment: Use `ssh -Y` to connect to the containerized application from a X11 server (desktop); the `-Y` option will set `DISPLAY` for you and forward the X11 calls from the client (server) to the desktop (client). X11 uses server and client in the opposite sense of modern applications.

Comment: I keep getting timeouts with `ssh -Y` to the container ip. Is there a way to pass it somehow when doing a `docker exec`?

Comment: No. Because the `ssh -Y` is being run from the host (not the container). Make sure you have ssh installed on the container. And [make sure X11 forwarding is enabled](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/12772/52050).

Comment: @AnisBenna hey, hope this will help https://stackoverflow.com/a/75271849/3153739