# Error with X11 socketing through Docker "Cannot open display" [Docker Desktop on Ubuntu 22.04, No ssh/vnc]

Tags: docker, x11, docker-desktop, ubuntu-22.04, x11-forwarding

I'm having problem with opening any X11 window (also plot windows from Python *OR* ROS scripts) from running Docker containers. In short, I always get similar "cannot open display" errors from different applications.

I am not looking for emulating desktop environment, ssh-forwarding or VNC virtualization.

#### Platform

Host: Ubuntu 22.04
Docker: Docker Desktop 4.15
Image: Tried firefox, xeyes etc. on plain ubuntu:latest or debian:latest images (e.g. *gns3/xeyes*, *sshipway/xclock*). Even I built several from scratch by Dockerfiles.

#### Run Command

```
docker run -it --network=host -e DISPLAY -v "/tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:rw" <image name>
```

I've tried also:

- `xhost +local:root`, `xhost +local:docker`, even `xhost +` before running container
- `--privileged`
- `--runtime=runc`
- `DISPLAY=127.0.1.1:1` (i.e. <localhost>:<host display>)
- `DISPLAY=unix$DISPLAY`

#### Extra Info

- Display env var in containers: `DISPLAY=:1`
- On host, there is no `~/.Xauthority`, instead `xauth` targets `/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority`
- I've checked [solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25281992/alternatives-to-ssh-x11-forwarding-for-docker-containers), [solution 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28395350/20786433) and [solution 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25280523/20786433), but still I am missing something.

Can QEMU/KVM virtualization layer be the root of the problem, as it is Docker Desktop (not Docker Engine only)?

Answer (score 1):

Update Feb.27, 2023: It seems that the magic IP `198.18.0.1` is related to a `tun` device created by my VPN application, which may handle all the traffic. After removing this device, I could not reproduce the correct result with the following method.

---

I had the **exact** settings with you (except for ubuntu 20.04, not 22.04), and tried many solutions for more than a whole day.

Here is what I found in the past day

1. X server did not listen to TCP by default
2. `--network=host` did not work as I thought, neither `:1` nor `127.0.0.1:1` solved the problem
3. when I ping any site (e.g. `ping google.com`) from within the docker container, it interprets it as `198.18.0.1`

I am not clear about the underlying mechanisms, but after trials, I solved the problem by

1. let X server listen to TCP by default via simply modifying `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` with

```bash
[security]
DisallowTCP=false

[xdmcp]
ServerArguments=-listen TCP
```

(assume your Desktop Manager is `gdm`, which may be the default one as of Ubuntu 17) and restart `gdm`

- to check this, use the command `nmap localhost` to see if `6001` (assume `$DISPLAY=:1`) or `X11` is shown (or any similar commands like `netstat -an | grep 6001`; `ps -ef | grep X` can be used to see if `Xorg` is run with `-listen tcp` argument)

2. run a docker container successfully with

```bash
xhost +
docker run \
    -it \
    --rm \
    -e DISPLAY=198.18.0.1$DISPLAY \
    xclock
```

where `xclock` is a simple image defined by such a `Dockerfile`

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y x11-apps
RUN apt-get install -y iproute2 \
    curl \
    iputils-ping \
    net-tools
CMD xclock
```

(the last apt layer was used for previous network debugging, one can omit it), then you should see a GUI clock shown on your monitor.

As for what this `198.18.0.1` mean, what I have known so far is that

1. it is contained in the output of `ifconfig`
2. it is the prefix `198.18.0` is contained in the output of `ping` called from within the docker container

Therefore, I guess it relates to some network interface that served as a bridge between the host and the docker container. However, this guess seems to conflict with my understanding of the host mode (and hence I remove the `--network=host`).

Furthermore, I finally did not map the UNIX socket file `/tmp/.X11-unix` as I found it did not affect the result. I am not sure if then the connection is fully transmitted through TCP instead of UNIX
socket file.

Remember to `xhost -` after trials. Disabling the firewall will be unnecessary, so just keep it open via `sudo ufw enable`. Again, I am unsure about the mechanism, or its safety issues.

I hurried to post this answer soon after I solve my issue, and might modify it later if any new discoveries pop out or mistakes exist. Hope any expert could correct my flaws and questions.

Comment: Good effort @Jimmy, I can also confirm this is a TCP-listening issue. Considering the update (on 27th Feb), your workaround is not very satisfying to me, though.

All in all, I gave up and went for Docker Engine, instead. It works as it should, even for 3D visualization apps.